# Need help solving why the 2nd For loop doesn't move away from its first character String

Tags: java, for-loop

Need help solving why the 2nd For loop doesn't move away from its first character String

Additionally, it would be nice if you could put it in simpler terms, as I am still learning Java.

how do i make the ch2 move forward to the next character string 
Because the reason i made it that way is so whatever I insert as a value (whether its 0100100 as long as its 1s and 0s) It can be separated by the For loop and identified by If/Else logic

conjunction logic gate

1 && 1 = 1

else 0

```
public static void main (String[]args)
{
    String A = "1010";
    char[] AsciiConvert = A.toCharArray();
    String B = "0011"; //←←← output of loop is 0000 not 0011
    char[] AsciiConvert2 = B.toCharArray();

    //48 = 0
    //49 = 1

    System.out.println("A \t B \t Output");

    String output = "";


    test:   
    for(char ch1:AsciiConvert)
    {
        int j = 0 , k = 0;

        if(ch1 == 48)
        {
            j = 0;
        }
        if(ch1 == 49)
        {
            j = 1;
        }
        System.out.print(ch1 + "\t ");
        for(char ch2:AsciiConvert2)
        {
            if(ch2 == 48)
            {
                k = 0;
            }
            if(ch2 == 49)
            {
                k = 1;
            }

            System.out.print(ch2);

            if(j == 1 && k == 1)
            {
                String conj1 = "1 ";
                output =(output + conj1);
                System.out.print("\t   " + conj1 + "\n");
            }
            else
            {
                String conj2 = "0 ";
                output =(output + conj2);
                System.out.print("\t   " + conj2 + "\n");
            }
            continue test;
        }
    }
}
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzN5R.png)

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to achieve, and also add the actual and the expected results .

Comment: conjuction logic

1 && 1 = 1 
else 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are not able to understand than see whole code of for loop.

```
for(int i=0;i<AsciiConvert.length;i++)
        {
            int j = 0 , k = 0;
            char ch1=AsciiConvert[i];
            if(ch1 == 48)
            {
                j = 0;
            }
            if(ch1 == 49)
            {
                j = 1;
            }
            System.out.print(ch1 + "\t ");
            for(int p=i;p<=i;p++)
            {
                char ch2=AsciiConvert2[p];
                if(ch2 == 48)
                {
                    k = 0;
                }
                if(ch2 == 49)
                {
                    k = 1;
                }

                System.out.print(ch2);

                if(j == 1 && k == 1)
                {
                    String conj1 = "1 ";
                    output =(output + conj1);
                    System.out.print("\t   " + conj1 + "\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    String conj2 = "0 ";
                    output =(output + conj2);
                    System.out.print("\t   " + conj2 + "\n");
                }
                continue test;
            }
        }
```

for explanation please see previous answer.

Comment: i did became confused, you never mentioned the

`char ch2=AsciiConvert2[p];` 

part. 

because im still ignorant about other ways of using this Ascii Convert, i only got this from the net `char ch1:AsciiConvert` when searching how to convert string into ascii

Comment: that is self describe but should put your efforts also.

Answer (score 0):

look your first for loop,second for loop are inside first loop.

now when first for loop execute first time, ch1=1 and then second loop execute only 1 time for ch2=0.

again, first loop execute for second time ch1=0 and then second loop start again because it is inside in first loop so it return ch=0.

all time your second loop execute once and return first value which is ch2=0.

Comment: then how do i make the ch2 move forward to the next character string
Because the reason i made it that way is so whatever I insert as a value (whether its 0100100 as long as its 1s and 0s)
It can be separated by the For loop and identified by If/Else logic  

conjunction logic gate
1 && 1 = 1
else
0

Comment: make your second loop dependent on first.like first loop                        for(int i=0;i<AsciiConvert.length;i++) inside first loop use second loop like for(int p=i;p<=i;p++)

Comment: or just use outer loop  for(int i=0;i<AsciiConvert.length;i++) and from first loop index get data from second array.

Comment: if i did that, how can the if/else identify the A & B strings both one by one

since im trying to output a conjunction logic, if both are 1s = 1
(this is for the answer 21 min ago)

Comment: all logic remain same no need to change anything